# Defining the value of a variable before a function?

Tags: plugins, functions, variables

I'm trying to edit a plugin so that it only shows it's submenu if the user is an administrator but I don't know how to define the value of the variable before the function:

```
function load_view( $name, $params = array(), $print_submenu_navigation = false ) {
```

My code so far is:

```
if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
 $print_submenu_navigation = true;  
}
else {
 $print_submenu_navigation = false;
}
```

If I put this before the function I get a php error telling me it's expecting a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong approach. `$print_submenu_navigation` will be filled in local scope when function is called with arguments, it's not a matter of global variables.

You want something like this when function is called (not defined):

```
load_view( 'name', array(), current_user_can('administrator') ) {
```

Alternatively you can add your snippet **inside** the function, then input value for `$print_submenu_navigation` will overwritten with result of your check.

And it's shorter to write it like this, function returns boolean:

```
$print_submenu_navigation = current_user_can('administrator');
```